# Find first x matches with re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I need limit re.findall to find first 3 matches and then stop.

for example

```
text = 'some1 text2 bla3 regex4 python5'
re.findall(r'\d',text)
```

then I get:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

and I want:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: You can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235770/how-to-limit-regexs-findall-method

Comment: or better here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902378/python-regular-expressions-limit-results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find N matches *and stop*, you could use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> import itertools as IT
>>> [item.group() for item in IT.islice(re.finditer(r'\d', text), 3)]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 10):

`re.findall` returns a list, so the simplest solution would be to just use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'some1 text2 bla3 regex4 python5'
>>> re.findall(r'\d', text)[:3]  # Get the first 3 items
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```